# gcloud ssh and gcloud ssh --command inconsistent environments

Tags: python, ssh, gcloud

I am new to gcp and the cli. I'm trying to write a script which creates a vm instance from deep learning image then runs a python script on it. Im following the doc here to create the deeplearning instance https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/create-start-instance#publicimage, and the cli works fine here.

When ssh'ing into the created instance and checking the packages with pip3 freeze I get all the long list of packages I'd expect from deeplearning image:

`gcloud compute ssh dl-instance` 
`user@dl-instance: pip3 freeze`

However, trying to do this all in one line with the --command option gives a much smaller list of packages, like four or something:

`gcloud compute ssh dl-instance --command "pip3 freeze"`

and i really don't have access to anything like numpy or typical python packages for deep learning. I've verified that the two methods are using the same user on the vm by running whoami. I have noticed that the $PATH's are different between the two methods. does anybody know why the environments are inconsistent between the two methods, and how to synchronize them? Any input is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Check which Linux shell is being started. I think the issue is the environment profiles that are automatically loaded. Figure out the environment variable differences and then look at the files such as .bashrc, .profile, etc. to know which ones are not being processed. You can then process them manually.

Comment: Thanks John good answer! Forgot the gamut of scripts run at startup. I found the offending file is /etc/profile.d/env.sh.

Answer (score 1):

John Hanley's comment is correct. THere are a number of scripts which are run when logging in. Using the answer at this link https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/334382/find-out-what-scripts-are-being-run-by-bash-at-login I was able to use strace to list all the valid files which are run by the shell. Looking at the contents of these I found that the file loading conda environment is /etc/profile.d/env.sh.

Explicitly, to make use of the image python environment I will have precede all commands with ". ./etc/profile.d/env.sh &&" when using the --command flag to gcloud ssh e.g.

gcloud compute ssh dl-instance --command=". /etc/profile.d/env.sh && python3 myscript.py"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).